# what is the difference between @within and @annotation in AOP

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

@within

This PCD limits matching to join points within types that have the given annotation:

```
@Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)")
```

@annotation

This PCD limits matching to join points where the subject of the join point has the given annotation. For example we may create a @Loggable annotation:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.baeldung.aop.annotations.Loggable)")
public void loggableMethods() {}
```

So does it mean that @annotation only applies for user defined or custom annotations.
and @within for Standard Annotatios

Comment: annotation: the *method* must have the annotation. within: the *type* (i.e. *class*) of the object containing the method must have the annotation. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54290855/592355

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be an older question, but just wanted to add the answer for more visibility.

It is as [JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) stated in the comment, the javadoc provides a clear difference between the two:

> @within: Limits matching to join points **within types that have the
>   given annotation** (the execution of methods declared in types with the
>   given annotation when using Spring AOP).
>
> @annotation: Limits matching to join points **where the subject of the
>   join point** (the method being executed in Spring AOP) **has the given
>   annotation.**

from https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators

Comment: Maybe to simplify it - within works for classes/interfaces, and annotation for methods