# Spring AOP can't double bind annotation

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Retry {

    int DEFAULT_RETRIES = 2;

    int times() default DEFAULT_RETRIES;
}
```

Which is used either on class level:

```java
@Retry(times = 5)
public class PersonServiceClass {

//...

    public void deletePerson(long id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Or method level (another class, not PersonServiceClass):

```java
@Retry
public void deletePerson(long id) {
    //...
}
```

The aspect is caught by such class:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class RetryInterceptor {

    @Around("@within(retry) || @annotation(retry)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Retry retry) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("around - " + retry);
        System.out.println("joinpoint - " + proceedingJoinPoint);
        return aroundHandler(proceedingJoinPoint, retry);
    }
```

And aspect is correctly caught on method or class level, but there is something wrong with binding `Retry` annotation.

When `@Around` is as following: `@Around("@within(retry) || @annotation(retry)")` then:

1. When caught on method level than `retry` is **binded**
2. When caught on class level than `retry` is **null**.

When `@Around` is as following `@Around("@annotation(retry) || @within(retry)")` then:

1. When caught on method level than `retry` is **null**.
2. When caught on class level than `retry`is **binded**.

*Spring Boot Parent Version - 2.1.1.RELEASE*

Comment: "|" is invalid token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...now you challenged me:) and i [could reproduce the issue](https://github.com/xerx593/soq54290855)!

Pragmatically I (would) solve(d) it like that:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

  @Around("@within(retry)")
  public Object typeAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Retry retry) throws Throwable {
    return commonAspect(joinPoint, retry);
  }

  @Around("@annotation(retry)")
  public Object methodAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Retry retry) throws Throwable {
    return commonAspect(joinPoint, retry);
  }

  private Object commonAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Retry retry) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Retry is :" + (retry == null ? "null" : retry.value()));
    // ... do your (common) stuff here
    return proceed;
  }

}
```

..welcome! :-)

And since you already have a (common) `aroundHandler()` method, it comes down to "introducing 2 public facades/PCDs for it".

Additional hint: Rename `times()` (if its the only/main property of that annotation) to: `value()`! ..then you can do "just" `@Retry(100)`.

Comment: do you know why `@Around("@within(retry) || @annotation(retry)")` doesn't bind to `@within(retry)`?

Comment: possibly  the best explanation on Stackoverflow regarding this topic!