# Spring AOP - How to pass in a different number of parameters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-annotations, aspect

I have an Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class BusinessAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(Business)")
    public Object getCorrespondingBusiness(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Business business) throws Throwable {

        //BEFORE METHOD EXECUTION
        Object data = joinPoint.getArgs()[0]; // gets first argument
        int businessNumber = business.value(); // gets # in annotation

        BusinessObj correspondingBusiness = getBusiness614(); // will make modular later

        // This is where ACTUAL METHOD will get invoke
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed( new Object[] { data, correspondingBusiness} );

        // AFTER METHOD EXECUTION
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }

    private BusinessObj getBusiness614() {
        return valid business..
    }
}
```

And here is the method that needs to access that correspondingBusiness object:

```
@Business(614)
    public BusinessRule rangeFromGreaterThanRangeThrough(BusinessProfile businessProfile) {
        return BusinessRule.businessRuleBuilder()
                .withParameter("from", ...)
                .withParameter("through", ...)
                .withCrudOperationAction(...)
                .withCrudOperationAction(...)
                .setBusiness(correspondingBusiness) // not recognizing the parameter. compilation error?
                ).build();
    }
```

Essentially, my issue is the correspondingBusiness object is not being recognized. I understand that you can manipulate and change parameters, but can you pass in extra parameters, or can you only change them? If I can only change them, how would I make it so I can call this method without having to pass in a second parameter? Creating an overload for each of these seems like a lot of unnecessary code.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is the annotation interface for clarity:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Business {
    int value();
}
```

Comment: can you add an example where you actually use the `@Business` annotation? what is the method interface?

Comment: @pero_hero, added! I accidentally had it listed as @BusinessRule()

Comment: `@annotation` is for (type level) annotations..(as far i remember)... for method annotations, try: `@within(business)` ..[see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54290855/592355)

Comment: (best i found) [current reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

Comment: can you extend the class `BusinessProfile` to hold a member of type `BusinessObj`? Then you could set it ine the aspect method? Or you could extend the mehtod interface to `public BusinessRule rangeFromGreaterThanRangeThrough(BusinessProfile businessProfile, BusinessObj obj)`

Comment: I think you misunderstand AOP. It does not work like that. You cannot expect a local variable defined in your aspect to magically be available in the target code. Spring AOP does not work on the source code level. The whole idea does not make sense, because even if if would work like that, your target class would have to know that there is an aspect preparing data for it. But core code should be unaware of AOP code. You are kind of reversing the whole AOP way of thinking here. What you want seems to be dependency injection, and Spring can do that for you already.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-names):

> The parameter binding in advice invocations relies on matching names used in pointcut expressions to declared parameter names in (advice and pointcut) method signatures.

Define your `Around` advice as shown below and `business` parameter will be passed to the advice method.

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(business)")
```

Comment: Business is referring to the annotation class Business. It's just a standard annotation with an integer value field. I'm attempting to pass in the value from the business annotation, get the rule, and inject it into the method. Example use: @Business(614). I've added the annotation to the question above.

Comment: Can you check documentation ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-names)) and try the suggested solution: replace `@Around("@annotation(Business)")` with `@Around("@annotation(business)")`

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be more understandable now.

Comment: for some reason, that still isn't working. i don't think it's being picked up when ran because @Around isn't recognizing the annotation?

Comment: Now I see the missing part, try with the following `@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(business)")` which will trigger the advice when any method with Business annotation is executed.